# PKCS#11 library for ACR122U USB

Tags: smartcard, pkcs#11, acr122

I bought an ACR122U USB smartcard reader but it came without an SDK or anything that could be installed other than the x64 unified driver I found at the OEM in Hong Kong.

I want to use it to properly access the cards. I also tried several PKCS libraries like PKCS#11.NET which I managed to recompile for 4.5 but it requires some driver DLLs (providers) that are not installed on my system.

Where can I get one of those? It lists these: 
    eTPKCS11g.dll
    opensc-pkcs11.dll
    etpkcs11.dll
    siecap11.dll
    rtPKCS11.dll

THe PKCS test application of PKCS#11.NET has two eTPKCS11 DLLs in a separate directory but they cannot be added as references. And as usual the project comes with ZERO documentation

Comment: I recommend to keep this question for the simple reason that the answer of guidot shows that looking for a PKCS#11 library that belongs to a *reader* is incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

Typically readers come without anything, since PCSC devices are mostly correctly recognized by Windows. Note, that the PKCS#11 driver depends to 100% on the card you use and to 0% on the reader, so the card supplier has to be queried next instead of the reader supplier, since the commands are quite different between several card manufacturers.